# RunListener equivalent in TestNG

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, testng, gherkin

I am converting my Cucumber-JUnit project to Cucumber-TestNg. 
In Junit, I used RunListener to grab Gherkin steps under execution. I used this listener to return me for a scenario  the step currently executing like: on step 'Given' condition or on step 'When' or on step 'Then' so on.
But in TestNg I could not find a similar listener that returns me the Gherkin scenario steps under execution. I tried other TestNg listeners, but i could not solve this problem. I find TestNg listeners are at test status related and not like JuNit RunListener. Suggest even if there is an alternative solution to this.

````
/**
 * Class used to do some report regarding the JUnit event notifier
 */
public class CustomJUnitListener extends RunListener {

  SeleniumTest test = null;

  public void setSeleniumTest(SeleniumTest test) {
    this.test = test;
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
            // Get which scenario step under execution at run time..here    
  }

}```

//--------
````

Make TestRunner to use this class @Runwith instaed of Cucumber.class

Comment: Can you please edit your question and please post a sample of what your JUnit's `RunListener` looks like?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [TestNG doc](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-testng-xml). You can use an `IInvokedMethodListener` or an `ITestListener` those listeners can help you to meet your goal.

For example, Using an `IInvokedMethodListener` you can implement something similar to this:

```
public class TestNGCustomInvokedMethodListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestNGCustomInvokedMethodListener.class);

  @Override
  public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, ITestResult iTestResult) {
   LOG.info("Running method: " + iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().getMethodName());
  }

  @Override
  public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod, ITestResult iTestResult) {

    LOG.info("Finished method: {} with result: {}", iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().getMethodName(), statusToString(iTestResult.getStatus()));
  }

  private String statusToString(int status) {
    String statusStr;
    switch (status) {
      case ITestResult.FAILURE:
        statusStr = "FAILURE";
        break;

      case ITestResult.SKIP:
        statusStr = "SKIP";
        break;

      case ITestResult.STARTED:
        statusStr = "STARTED";
        break;

      case ITestResult.SUCCESS:
        statusStr = "SUCCESS";
        break;

     default:
        statusStr = "undefined";
        break;
    }

    return statusStr;
  }
}
```

Finally you can take a look to [this post](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-listeners/), that explains very well how to use an configure TestNG Listeners.